# In the Megaman TCG, what does a collector number that starts with "4" indicate?

Tags: card-rarity, megaman-nt-warrior-tcg

The collector's numbers on most cards in the [Megaman Trading Card Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/13091/megaman-nt-warrior-trading-card-game) list the set number, the rarity, and the number within the set for the given card.

Because there were only three sets released, I expected the set numbers to be only 1, 2, and 3. However, some of my cards have a 4 in the set number position.

Some examples are BambooLance (4 U 35), BugCharge (4 U 38), Geyser (4 U 40), and MagBolt3 (4 U 42).

What does the 4 mean on these cards?

Comment: I added a tag and a board game geek link. If you are referring to some other game, feel free to revert my change or make further edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These cards were misprinted. The set number is supposed to be 3, just like the other cards in the set.

I found this answer in a supplement to the Grave starter deck rulebook titled "MegaMan Trading Card Game - Current Rulings Document 2.0 - 4/1/2005".

The list of cards that were misprinted in this way are:

- BambooLance (3U35)
- BugCharge (3U38)
- Geyser (3U40)
- MagBolt3 (3U42)
- Muramasa (3U44)
- VoodooDoll (3U46)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to refer to the Gameboy Advance games that featured these items. If I look at [this list](https://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/918999-mega-man-battle-network-4-red-sun/faqs/28446) of in-game items for Megaman Battle Network 4 for the GBA, it lists all these items.